# How to interact with already running process using java

Tags: java, process

Lets say i already have an application running in my computer (hlds.exe)
Now how do i actually send commands to it. It is running using console. I need to send commands "restart", "ChangeLevel" using java.
How do i do that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is only possible if that process has opened a channel to which your process can send inputs at all; if it runs in a console as you seem to imply, the chances that this is the case are very close to 0.

Comment: There are many ways for processes to interact. Command-line arguments aren't possible since the other process has already been started. Other possibilities include sockets, pipes, files, shared memory ...

Comment: I just found one solution using a jar file Rcon.jar. But the issue is even though the service is running locally on my machine, i am not able to connect to the service. It is using Sockets

Answer (score 0):

Starting from J2SE 5.0 release Java Management Extensions (JMX) was introduced to provide a mechanism form managing resources dynamically at runtime. It is an excellent way to manage/obtain current state of any running application.

The JMX can be achieved by creating Managed Beans (MBeans) and then register it to the MBean Server.

For more details read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/)